# No link through an image

Tags: html, css

Please I have an image as a link to another page and I have a menu of 2 text options (using ul&li) When I use only my image, it works, but when I try to put everything together, my image doesn't link, only the menu works. My code run in Chrome and Explorer, I can't see where the problem is. Someone please help me.

Thanks!

Here my html code:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">

           <div id="home">
              <a href="home.html"><img id="flores" src="images/flores.jpg" alt="home" /></a>
           </div>

           <div id="connexion">
              <section id="formulario">
                  <p id="titulo">Mi cuenta</p>
                  <form action="" method="get">
                      ...
                  </form>
              </section>
           </div>

           <div id="contenido">
               <div id="contenido_menu">
                   <ul>
                       <li><a href="rosa.html">Rosa</a></li>
                       <li><a href="jasmin.html">Jasmin</a> </li>
                   </ul> 
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My css code:

```
#container{
    position: relative;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:150px;
    width:1024px;
    height:768px;
    background-color: grey;
}
#header{
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    width:1024px;
    height: 150px;
}

#home{
    position:absolute;
    width:624px;
    height:150px; 
}

#flores {
    margin-top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}


#contenido{ 
    position:absolute;
    margin: auto;
    width:1024px;
    height:438px;
    background-color: pink;
}
#contenido_menu{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:5px; 
    background-image: url("img/rosas.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width:619px;
    height:95px;
    line-height:95px;
    float:left;
}
#contenido_menu ul{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#contenido_menu li{
    display:inline;
    padding-top: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
#contenido_menu a:link, #contenido_menu a:visited{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size:19px; 
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#1a53ff;
    height:40px;
    padding:30px 50px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any image inside `li` tags

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I can imagin is that some div or the menu is over the picture. Try to check it with an tag inspector from your debugging tools.

Answer (score 1):

Check your code properly.

In the html you have given the location of flores.jpg as "images/flores.jpg".
While for the other image rosas.jpg, in your css you typed the location as "img/rosas.jpg".

Check whether both images are in their respective folders, or you might have typed one of them wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the below declaration. Remove `padding-top:50%`. I hope by mistake you put `%` instead `px`.

```
 #contenido_menu li{
 display:inline;
 padding-top: 50px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 }
```

Also remove `position:absolute` from `#home` class.

```
#home{
/*position:absolute;*/
width:624px;
height:150px; 
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/pL00uu2s/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You positioned the home and the menu div absolute, if I remove absolute it works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/2m8rmvuh/

**Edit:** Linked to an old fiddle, now its the correct one ;)

```
#home{
width:624px;
height:150px;  
}

#contenido{ 
margin: auto;
width:1024px;
height:438px;
background-color: pink;
}
#contenido_menu{
margin-top:5px; 
background-image: url("img/rosas.jpg");
background-size: 100% 100%;
width:619px;
height:95px;
line-height:95px;
float:left;
}
```

I dont know if thats the look you want, but if you give them the attribute absolute, they are overlapping, if you use a large picture.